# How to define CSS font size within font tags?

Tags: html, fonts

I have written all my HTML code using the font tag.
I used size="2" and size="3"

Is it possible to define a main CSS style in which I define the sizes for these fonts?

```
<font size="2">Hello 1</font>
<font size="3">Hello 2</font>
```

Thanks a lot guys

Comment: I guess WHY is the question. FONT has been deprecated and should not be used.

Comment: First, say `span class="size2"` instead of `font size="2"` in the HTML. Then, use CSS `.size2 { font-size: 10pt; }` and similar for size 3. However, you need to use points for CSS. Generally, size 2 is 10pt and size 3 is 12pt. http://www.microsoft.com/typography/web/designer/face3.htm

Comment: By the way, `font` is long obsolete. Steer way clear of it; it's harder to write something the right way once than rewrite it.

Answer (score 3):

Of course you can. Try adding this to a css style included in your page:

```
font[size="2"] {
   font-size: 20px;
}

font[size="3"] {
   font-size: 30px;
}
```

Naturally you have to choose the size you prefer.
By the way, the `<font>` tag is obsolete, and you should not use it. Use `<span>` and assign it a class, instead.

Further reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `<font>` is obsolete.

Second of all, yes, you can! Although I'd recommend not using the `size` attribute.  With span, I'd recommend using something like `class="small"`.  Set the size by using the following code:

```
span.small
{
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually FONT tag has been deprecated and should not be used. 
It's not supported in HTML5, though I had already written a huge piece of code using such tags.

Thanks a lot guys :)